# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: | even though it really exists

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

So the first portion of my code words but the second portion is where I start to get errors.

````
card_info = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe"))
card_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number" ] ')
card_info.send_keys("1234")
card_info.send_keys("5678")
billinfo = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe"))
time.sleep(3)
billinfo = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe"))
billinfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="name"]')
billinfo.send_keys("johnd")```
````

Comment: It means Selenium cannot find your element. Add html code of the page or a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you switching to multiple iframes? Are the iframes nested?

You can try using [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to get elements. e.g

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...

try:
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "card-fields-iframe"))
    )
except:
    # handle element not found
```

Comment: Yes I am switching through multiple frames. So what I used to switch to iframe is driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe")) . I also am using a time.sleep(3) timer after it gets through the shipping process to make sure the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Can you provide the html code of the site?

Comment: The site is https://kith.com . The html should be on the last screen which is the checkout screen that asks to put in the name, cc number, cvv number, etc.

Comment: just add a random product to cart and get to the checkout screen